# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(tasks[0])')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I'm trying to get the key of an array of object, i got length and items keys successfully, but when i try to include their indexs i'm getting above error, check below to understand more.

this is what I have:

```
{"task1": [{"en": [Array]}, {"ku": [Array]}], "task2": [{"en": [Array]}, {"ku": [Array]}]}
```

When i try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const checkIfCorrect = newData.map((data) => {
    return data.map((dataItems) => {
      return dataItems.map((tasks, i) => {
        return console.log(Object.keys(tasks)); // <-----
      });
    });
  });
}, [newData]);
```

Results in:

```
["task1", "task2"]
```

An when I try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const checkIfCorrect = newData.map((data) => {
    return data.map((dataItems) => {
      return dataItems.map((tasks, i) => {
        return console.log(Object.keys(tasks).length); // <-----
      });
    });
  });
}, [newData]);
```

Results in:

```
2
```

And when I try this!

```
useEffect(() => {
  const checkIfCorrect = newData.map((data) => {
    return data.map((dataItems) => {
      return dataItems.map((tasks, i) => {
        return console.log(Object.keys(tasks[0])); // <-----
      });
    });
  });
}, [newData]);
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(tasks[0])')
```

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: you log the tasks[0] and see result

Comment: What is the expected output here. ?

Comment: tasks is an object not an array, so tasks[0] gives you undefined

Comment: maybe you mean dataItems[0]?

Comment: When i log tasks[0] it returns undefined

Comment: And dataItems[0] returns both keys